# Getting total number of clicked items in jQuery php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am developing a online bus booking website like redbus using an api service.
Stuck with calculating the total amount of booked seats.

Here is the work flow

Getting list of buses from api and shows them in an html table:

```
<?php $i=0; foreach($result['apiAvailableBuses'] as $value){?>

    ?>
      //display each bus details
    <?php }?>
```

Make an ajax request to getting the each bus seat structure with some parameters (ajax request is in a loop).

```
$.ajax({
             url:'<?php echo base_url();?>agentdashboard/ajax_buslayout',
             method:"POST",
             data:{
                  source:$("input[name=source]").val(),
                  dest:$("input[name=dest]").val(),
                  doj:$("input[name=doj]").val()
                },
             success:function(data){
                 $('#result'+id).html(data);

             },
             error:function(err){

             }
          });
```

php code

```
foreach($result['seats'] as $value)
{
  echo "<div class='seat $booked' data-number='$seat' $book_seat amount='$total'><img src='".base_url()."assets/images/seat.png' width='20' height='20' title='$seat'></div>";
}
 echo "<div class='clearfix'></div><br><center><strong id='amount'>Amount:0</strong></center>";
```

When click on each seat I will store the clicked seat numbers to `seat_count` array to find the total amount.

```
$(document).on("click",".seat",function(){
  //store the number of clicked seats.
  var seat_count = [];
  //seat number of each seat.
  var seat_no = $(this).attr("data-number");
    seat_count.push(seat_no);    
    alert(seat_count.length);
    $("#amount").text('Amount: '+seat_count.length * amount);
});
```

But the problem is I can't get the values in `seat_count` array, I get only one value .

```
alert(seat_count.length)
```

only returns 1.

Comment: seat_count looks local and reset each click. Try making it global, outside the on click.

Comment: How? i tried dynamic variable method,but didn't worked

Comment: Can you show the code on how you declared it global?

Comment: `var seat_no = $(this).data("number");` have you tried this!? I thinks this might work

Comment: You can't use $(this) outside the click, it passes an object. It should just be var seat_count = []; then your method.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the 'var seat_count = [];' outside the click event handler function. Every time 'seat_count' is getting re-initialized.

Comment: The whole ajax request is repeated in foorloop

Answer (score 0):

```
var seat_count = [];
$(document).on("click", ".seat", function () {
    //seat number of each seat.
    var seat_no = $(this).attr("data-number");
    seat_count.push(seat_no);
    alert(seat_count.length);
    $("#amount").text('Amount: ' + seat_count.length * amount);
});
```

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: what if user unselects same seat?

Comment: Amount will be deducted

Comment: What is .seat ? Which kind of input ?
It would be great if you'll provide your HTML